# MySQL Workbench remove backtick from registered views

Tags: mysql-workbench

Is there a way to make Workbench keep using backtick?

I use MySQL Workbench for a long time.
For some reason, some of our old table have "human reading" field name, like "mobile phone 1".
So far Workbench always use back tick, and this is how we registred our views.

Now I installed a new computer, with a new installation of workbench.
But everytime I want to open a view, there are no backtick and workbench recognise it as an error (obviously), saying "Error Parsing DDL for .... There was an error while parsing the DDL retrived from the server. Do you want to view the DDL or cancel processing it?"

That's funny because most of posts are from people annoyed by backtick.

Thanks guys.

edit : I went on some other computer. Views works great. I can edit them, backticks are there.
So

1. I opened the view create query (with backtick)
2. I copy/paste it into the other computer workbench, to create the same query blablamyquery2. The text is fine, the editor shows no error
3. I save the query : error "Error Parsing DDL for .... There was an error while parsing the DDL retrived from the server. Do you want to view the DDL or cancel processing it?"

Fun thing is : the view is created. I can refresh and see it. I can open it from the other computer, but not from the new one.

The new one has windows 10 pro, and the old one windows 10 home. Could that cause such an issue ?

Comment: `That's funny because most of posts are from people annoyed by backtick.` It's also funny how the *lack* of backticks when they're needed (like in your case) will annoy people even more.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys

Just for you know, if someone has the same problem, here is how I found a workaround : downgrade from 8.0.33 to another stable version.

Now I can edit views and everything, backticks are back, everything works smooth.

Sure, there may be smarter ways around, but this is a solution.